# Magento 2 : Add custom validation to shipping address

Tags: magento2

When user enters shipping address I want to validate it using an external API (for example: USPS street-level validation API)..

Which file do I extend to add this validation in the checkout? `checkout_index_index.xml` does not have the specific address fields.

Comment: did you find te solution